# How to interpret the intuitive idea behind Szemerédi regularity lemma?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I'm reading a text discussing [Szemerédi regularity lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma).

[image]

I'm not sure I understand the difference between the quasirandom part and the structured part as stated in the text. Also the analysis of number of edges in the error part is not clear. I'd like to ask for further clarification and examples if possible.